# Before/After Plugin [javascript/jquery] does not load correctly after auto size adjustment

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

First of all: It's my first time using javascript.
I wanted to implement the [Before/After Plugin](http://www.catchmyfame.com/catchmyfame-jquery-plugins/jquery-beforeafter-plugin/) into Powerpoint. So I created a html file that I loaded with a webbrowser object in Powerpoint. That worked basically but the plugin requires me to define the height and width statically for the pictures I use:

```
<html>
 <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>SomeTitle</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div><img alt="before" src="pics1/before.jpg" width="3696" height="1583" /></div>
        <div><img alt="after" src="pics1/after.jpg" width="3696" height="1583" /></div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.beforeafter-1.4.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $('#container').beforeAfter({
            imagePath: 'js/',
            showFullLinks: false
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

So I wanted to implement the function that the size is statically defined but determined once in the beginning by the size of the screen. After experimenting a bit I found a solution that works partly:

```
<html>
 <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>SomeTitle</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="container"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
var wi=screen.availWidth-20;
var img1=document.createElement("img");
img1.alt="before";
img1.src="pics1/before.jpg";
img1.height=wi*img1.height/img1.width;
img1.width=wi;
document.getElementById("container").appendChild(img1);

var img2=document.createElement("img");
img2.alt="after";
img2.src="pics1/after.jpg";
img2.height=wi*img2.height/img2.width;
img2.width=wi;
document.getElementById("container").appendChild(img2);
/* ]]> */
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.beforeafter-1.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#container').beforeAfter({
        imagePath: 'js/',
        showFullLinks: false
        });
    });
/* ]]> */
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The problem now is/are following:

- Firefox: Does not load the pictures at the first time but after refreshing it works perfectly.
- IExplorer: It does not show anything.
- Chrome: It does not show aynthing.
- Powerpoint WebBrowser: It does not show aynthing.

I already tried to fix by the "$(document).ready(function() {..." part but it does not help at all.
What's wrong here?

Comment: First time using js? And already using jquery? Learn -> try -> learn -> try ->ask. Youve missed a few parts...

Comment: @Jonas w I'm not planning to learn javascript at the moment but this beforeafter function is something we need at work and I am the only one who actively programs at all. That's why I already use jquery. Can you correct my code or give me some hints to fix it, please?